# How does ExpressVPN work in OS X?

Tags: macos, vpn

I've just installed ExpressVPN, which connects via an app. While it's connected, there is no extra VPN connection listed in `System Preferences->Network`, and the menu bar VPN status does not indicate that it is connected. **It is working fine**, so my question is purely out of interest:

How does this VPN work, under the hood? How does this app cause all network traffic to go through the VPN connection, when it doesn't set up a system VPN?

Comment: Are you seeing it work at all? What tells you it is working? Please edit a little more into the question to avoid having close votes as too broad.

Comment: @bmike Cheers, hopefully my edit has clarified things.

Comment: Perhaps the architecture described here will be of some help https://security.stackexchange.com/a/112146/191986